# $f \in Aut (\mathbb{D})$ with two fixed points is the identity

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I have been working on this homework problem for my complex analysis class for some time to no avail.  The questions asks for me to show that for $f \in Aut (\mathbb{D})$ such that $f(z_1) = z_1$ and $f(z_2) = z_2$ for $z_1 \ne z_2 \in \mathbb{D}$, $f$ is the identity on $\mathbb{D}$: $f(z) = z$ for all $z \in \mathbb{D}$.
If we assume that one of the fixed points, say $z_1$ is zero so that $f(0) = 0$, then the result follows nicely from Schwarz' Lemma.  However, in the case when both $z_1$ and $z_2$ are non-zero I am having difficulty.  It seems like this case should somehow be able to be deduced from the $z_1 = 0$ case, but I have not found out how to do this yet.
As always, any guidance would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Can you compose your function with another one such that the composition satisfies Schwarz?

Comment: I tried this and here is where I got:
 $f \in Aut (\mathbb{D})$ gives that $f = \phi _{-b} \circ R_{\alpha}$ where 
$$ \phi_{b}(z) = \frac{z-b}{1-\bar{b}z} $$
and $R_{\alpha}$ is rotation by $\alpha$ such that $\mid \alpha \mid = 1$.  
I considered trying to use $h(z) := (\phi_{b} \circ f)(z)$.
Indeed, $h$ satisfies Schwarz, but I was having difficulty seeing how this helped our case...Is this where you were going?

Comment: Not quite where I was going, but on your way. If you could write $h = \phi_b \circ f \circ \phi_{-b}$ with h satisfying Schwarz, then I think you would be done. I haven't mentally solved the problem, and I don't want to solve it for you, but this is the direction I would try. Or something close to this

Answer (score 0):

First what is the most general form for automorphisms of the unit disk?
Assume without loss of generality that this fixes zero
and try to fix another point different from zero and see that you come up with the identity
infact the only fixed point is zero