# How are fixed points and Schwarz lemma related?

Tags: complex-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

I'm trying to understand this strange exercise in complex analysis:

Let $f : D → \mathbb{C}$ be analytic and $|f(z)| < 1$ for all $z \in D$, and suppose that $f$ has two distinct fixed points
$a, b \in D$. Set $T_\alpha(z) := (z − \alpha)/(1 − \bar{\alpha}z)$.
By considering the function $T_\alpha \circ f \circ T_{−\alpha}$ with an appropriate $\alpha \in D$, show that $f(z) = z$ for all $z$ in $D$.

What is $T_\alpha$ doing here? Can I accomplish anything by taking that function into consideration? And how can I show that $f$ is the identity map. If I apply Schwarz lemma somehow, I can probably not show anything more than that $f$ is a rotation map, or in other words that $f(z) = \lambda z$ where the absolute value of $\lambda$ is 1.

Comment: For that last part: thanks to $f$ having two fixed points, are you sure you do not know how to conclude that $\forall z \in D,\, f(z) = \lambda z$ implies $\lambda = 1$?

Comment: This has been asked and answered before:  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/801570/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/271838/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/947910/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/674423/42969 – all found with [this search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcomplex-analysis%5D+schwarz+fixed+points)